# Strange behaviour of ValidationMessageFor when used with nullable int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to authenticate the input to a  @Html.EditorFor() field with unobtrusive validation in my ASP.NET 4.5 project.
The input should be an integer value or empty.

Model:

```
public class Result  
{  
    [Display(Name="Number")]  
    [Range(0, 10000, ErrorMessage = "Value out of bounds")]  
    public int? number{ get; set; }  
}
```

and my Razor .cshtml:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST" }))  
{  
    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.number)
    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.number)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.number)  

    <input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
}
```

When I run the code I get the website and entering input works like expected but the validation doesn't work like expected.

If I enter a value >10000 or <0 I get an error message but if I enter letters instead of digits no error message is displayed. If I enter a combination of letters and digits I get the error message "Das Feld "Number" muss eine Zahl sein. (The field "Number" has to be a number)" if the input starts with a digit and no error if the input starts with a letter.

Error: "10001", "-1", "1a"
No Error: "100", "abc", "abc123", "a a 1"

I want to get an error message when I enter a non integer value into the input field but I don't see how I could change this.

I tried using [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]+[0-9]*", ErrorMessage="Number Error")] but this caused no noticeable change and setting the value to [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number Error")] doesn't work because this displays an error message if something is written to input and then deleted.

How do I get the code to display an error message every time a non integer value is entered?

Comment: Why don't you declare the variable as a non-nullable instead? Then, you can convert null values to 0s.

Comment: @JosianeFerice 0 does not mean the same thing as null.

Comment: I still want to be able to differentiate between no user input to a filed or the value 0 as input.